# Script for keeping a cache directory a specific size and removing based on last accessed

Tags: bash, scripts, filesystem, cron, cache

I need a script that will check the size of a directory and if it's bigger than a specified size it will go through and delete x number of files until it's below the threshhold size again. And I would like the files to be deleted based on last accessed so files that haven't been used in a while get's removed first.

I'm not sure if there is any software avalible for handling this already?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually quite simple:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
max_size=2000 # size in kilobytes
i=0
while [[ $(du -s "$1" | awk '{print $1}') > $max_size ]]; do
  i=$(($i+1))
  [[ -z "$file_list" ]] && file_list="$(find "$1" -type f -printf '%T@ %P\n' | sort -n | sed 's/[^ ]* //')"
  rm -f "$(head -n$i <<<"$file_list" | tail -n1)"
done
```

Start it like `/path/to/script.sh /path/to/dir` and it will test whether `/path/to/dir` exceeds `max_size` (in kilobytes) and if so delete the oldest files one after another until `max_size` is matched or undercut. **Be careful, this deletes files without mercy**, run it in a terminal with `rm -i` instead of `rm -f` to test its functionality.

To start the script periodically, create a cronjob with `crontab -e` like e.g.

```
@weekly /path/to/script.sh /path/to/dir
```

to run it weekly.

Comment: Hey, I should use `-printf '%A@ %P\n'` if I want it sorted by last accessed instead of last modified, right?

Comment: Also it seems like rm only gets the filename and not the full path to the file so it does not work if the scrip isnt in the same folder as the files it needs to delete?

Comment: @MichaelLindfors Yes, `%A@` instead of `%T@` for last accessed. I forgot `/path/to/dir` in the cron line and edited it, however this should work no matter where the script is located.